# ApiCompatibilityLevel {Get; Set} Error Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small problem and here it is

```
// Rebuild asset bundle files
        EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
        PlayerSettings.colorSpace = ColorSpace.Linear;
        PlayerSettings.GetApiCompatibilityLevel = PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone,ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_2_0);
```

and the error is

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

The second one is

```
static void Build_Android_Release(string[] scenes, short eCVC, bool bRelease = true){
    //lets change the platform
    EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTargetGroup.Android); 
}
```

and the error says :

> !The best overloarded method match for "UnityEditor.EditorUserBuilsettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(UnityEditor.BuildTarget)' has some invalid arguments
>
> !Argument `#1' cannot convert` UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup' expression to type `UnityEditor.BuildTarget'

Comment: As a side note, you should not ask several questions in one post on Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that individual questions are best searched and reused by other people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first error,

```
PlayerSettings.GetApiCompatibilityLevel = PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone,ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_2_0);
```

Should be replaced by

```
PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone,ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_2_0);
```

---

For your second error, you use `BuildTargetGroup` instead of `BuildTarget` (as the error suggests).

You need to use :

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTarget.Android);
```

Comment: ill acccept this as an aswer. but i cant right now because it is 8 minutes ago . Thank you so much